# difference between using super() and super(ViewName,self)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-context

I have been using  in generic views (CBVs)

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

but I've noticed that people here do:

```
context = super(ClassViewName,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

is there is a difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is python version supported syntax.
In python 3 you would use

`context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)`

while in python 2 you would use

`context = super(ClassViewName,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`

this is true for any `super` method call

see: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function